# SimpleOnGestureListener code not working in Android 2.2

Tags: android, swipe, gesturedetector, onfling

I have some code that I wrote to implement a vertical swipe on a
Gallery widget.  It works great in Android 1.5 and 1.6 but does not
work in Android 2.2 (I have yet to try it with 2.1).

```
public class SwipeUpDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
implements OnTouchListener
{
       private GestureDetector m_detector;

       public SwipeUpDetector()
       {
               m_detector = new GestureDetector(m_context, this);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
       {
               if (Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) < s_swipeMaxOffPath &&
                       e1.getY() - e2.getY() >= s_swipeMinDistance &&
                       Math.abs(velocityY) >= s_swipeMinVelocity)
               {
                       int pos = m_gallery.pointToPosition((int)e1.getX(), (int)e2.getY());
                       startAnimation(pos);

                       return true;
               }

               return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
       {
               return m_detector == null ? false : m_detector.onTouchEvent(event);
       }
}
```

And to be able to get my gallery to detect the onFling I have the
following:

```
   m_gallery.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeUpDetector());
```

In Android 1.5 and 1.6 this works great.  In Android 2.2 onFling() is
never called.  In looking around on Google and StackOverflow I found
one possible solution was to implement onDown() and return true.

However, I am also listening to single clicks and have a context menu
listener set up on this gallery.  When I implement onDown() and return
true I do indeed get the swipe to work.  But when I do this the
context menu doesn't display on a long click and the single clicks
don't work either... Clicking on items in the gallery cause the
gallery to jump around and I don't get any feedback when I click on an
item in the gallery.  It just immediately makes that item the selected
item and moves it to the center.

I looked at the API differences report between 1.6, 2.1, and 2.2 and
didn't see anthing of significance that could have caused this to
break...

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT:

It might also be helpful to know that the gallery is nested inside a couple layouts as follows (this isn't a complete layout... it is just intended to show the hierarchy of where this Gallery lives):

```
 <ScrollView>
      <LinearLayout>
           <RelativeLayout> <!-- This relative layout is a custom one that I subclassed -->
                <Gallery />
           </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

### EDIT #2:

Here are the requested layouts... There are two of them, for reusability purposes.  Here is the first one, which is the main activity's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myns="http://com.magouyaware/appswipe"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/appdocks_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
    >
        <com.magouyaware.appswipe.TitledGallery
            android:id="@+id/running_gallery_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            myns:gallery_title="@string/running_title"
        />

        <com.magouyaware.appswipe.TitledGallery
            android:id="@+id/recent_gallery_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            myns:gallery_title="@string/recent_title"
        />

        <com.magouyaware.appswipe.TitledGallery
            android:id="@+id/favs_gallery_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            myns:gallery_title="@string/favs_title"
        />

        <com.magouyaware.appswipe.TitledGallery
            android:id="@+id/service_gallery_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            myns:gallery_title="@string/service_title"
        />

        <com.magouyaware.appswipe.TitledGallery
            android:id="@+id/process_gallery_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            myns:gallery_title="@string/process_title"
        />

        <include 
            android:id="@+id/indeterminate_progress_layout_id" 
            layout="@layout/indeterminate_progress_layout" 
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is the layout file for com.magouyaware.appswipe.TitledGallery... This is nothing more than a RelativeLayout subclass for the purpose of controlling several views as a single item in the code and for reusability:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titled_gallery_main_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@null"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titled_gallery_expansion_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titled_gallery_expansion_image_id"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clickable="false"
        />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TitleText"
            android:id="@+id/titled_gallery_title_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="1sp"
            android:paddingRight="10sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/titled_gallery_text_color_selector"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clickable="false"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/titled_gallery_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titled_gallery_expansion_layout_id"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:spacing="5sp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:unselectedAlpha=".5"
        android:focusable="false"
    />

    <TextView 
        style="@style/SubTitleText"
        android:id="@+id/titled_gallery_current_text_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titled_gallery_id"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I should probably clarify that when I say I never get into the onFling() method that I mean I never get into that method for a vertical fling... I always get into that method if I fling left to right or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I was able to receive single/double clicks and long click as well by implementing *onSingleTapConfirmed*, *onDoubleTap* and *onLongPress* in my implementation of *SimpleOnGestureListener* (while returning **true** from *onDown*).</del>

Concerning why we should override `onDown` method. I think it is related to the [issue #8233](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8233). It was reported one year ago against 2.1 version. Since only 10 people starred it so far I guess it would not be fixed in the near future.

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the issue was caused by the combination of `ScrollView` and `Gallery` and usage of `OnTouchListener`. `Gallery` itself implements `OnGestureListener` and encapsulates `GestureDetector` which is disabled when we set our *OnTouchListener*, resulting in a strange gallery behavior sometimes. On the other hand if we just subclass Gallery component and perform long-click/swipe detection in its onLongPress/onFling methods the parent ScrollView will intercept vertical move events preventing onFling call for such events. The solution is to override `Gallery.dispatchTouchEvent` and call [`requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) for gallery parent.

To summarize: if you want to detect swipes (long-, double-clicks etc.) for the Gallery (and possibly place it inside the ScrollView) use the custom component provided below instead of GestureDetector/OnTouchListener.

```
public class FlingGallery extends android.widget.Gallery implements OnDoubleTapListener {

  private static final int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 30;   // 30dp, set to the desired value

  private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;   // 50dp, set to the desired value

  private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 40;   // 40dp, set to the desired value

  private final float mSwipeMinDistance;

  private final float mSwipeMaxOffPath;

  private final float mSwipeMinVelocity;

  public FlingGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    this.mSwipeMinDistance = density * SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE;
    this.mSwipeMaxOffPath = density * SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH;
    this.mSwipeMinVelocity = density * SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY;
  }

  public FlingGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.galleryStyle);
  }

  public FlingGallery(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final ViewParent parent;
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && (parent = getParent()) != null) {
      parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);  // this will be passed up to the root view, i.e. ScrollView in our case
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
  // Your double-tap handler...
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
  // Your single-tap handler...
    return true;
  }    

  @Override
  public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
  // Your long-press handler...
    super.onLongPress(event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (e1 == null) {
      return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
    float dx = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
    float dy = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
    if (abs(dx) < mSwipeMaxOffPath && abs(velocityY) > mSwipeMinVelocity && abs(dy) > mSwipeMinDistance) {
      if (dy > 0) {
        // Your from-top-to-bottom handler...
      } else {
        // Your from-bottom-to-top handler...
      }
    } else if (abs(dy) < mSwipeMaxOffPath && abs(velocityX) > mSwipeMinVelocity && abs(dx) > mSwipeMinDistance) {
      if (dx > 0) {
        // Your from-left-to-right handler...
      } else {
        // Your from-right-to-left handler...
      }
    }
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a Gallery view?  I think my problem might be specific to using a Gallery view.  When I return true from onDown() and try to implement those methods my Gallery jumps around like crazy and I don't get any visual feedback from my selector (i.e. background color changes based on the pressed/selected/focused states).  Also I never get into the onLongPress, onDoubleTap, and onSingleTapConfirmed methods...

Comment: Looking at the bug it does seem like the exact problem I am facing... Unfortunately the workaround listed does not work in my case

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with Gallery view.

Comment: I tried it on the layout you provided - and it worked (I even created custom RelativeLayout as you do).
Just to clarify, my GestureListener does not implement `OnTouchListener`. Instead I'm attaching it to the Gallery like this:
`final GestureListener gst = new GestureListener(context, this);
      OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gst.onTouchEvent(event);
      }
    };
    view.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);`

Comment: As an update, I was able to get all the methods to get hit, including the onFling() method.  However, when I get to this point I lose all user-feedback from my custom selector (if it is focused it has a blue gradient background, if currently pressed it has a red gradient background and if selected has an orange gradient).  Also... I as soon as I touch an item the current selection changes, without waiting for whether it is a single-tap, double-tap, long press, or swipe.  I'll try changing it how you are doing it to see what happens

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your layout. Can you please post layout details (including the attributes)? This can speed up issue identification.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering... I'm editing my post above to contain your requested information

Comment: I have tested the layout you provided and it works well - detecting taps (single/double) and vertical flings as well. Tested under Android 2.2 emulator.

Comment: When you perform a long-press on the emulator, does the item pressed on immediately switch to the center?  That is the behavior on my phone (T-Mobile MyTouch 3G 1.2 running Android 2.2.1)

Comment: I don't observe such behavior. I created a test project - you can  compare it to yours, maybe it will help to resolve your issue. I will send you a mail. (And yeah, it's not an April 1st hoax ;-) ).

Comment: Unfortunately the sample you sent me still has problems with long press... I sent an email explaining how to reproduce it.

Comment: Idolon has helped me figure out the cause of the problem and how to solve it.  At least in my specific case, I needed to get rid of the ScrollView... As soon as I removed it everything started working again.  In my case I was able to restructure my app so I didn't need it.  I believe Idolon has come up with a way to make the ScrollView and Gallery view work together, so maybe he can post that solution here as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not handle the down you will not get any event (scroll, fling, up) linked to this down event. So you must return true.

I tried to understand why but I failed yet. Maybe since `SimpleOnGestureListener` returns false by default, and some new 2.2 optimizations in the outer Layout feels you do not want the event. You are not a valid target anymore for the chain of events.

To get your longPress working, can't you implement the `onLongPress` event in your detector and call the code that makes your menu appear?

Comment: As mentioned in my post, when I implement onDown() and try to process single clicks (including onLongPress) the Gallery view jumps around sporadically and gives all sorts of wild behavior...